# Get rid of Mongo $ signs in JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, flask, python-3.4, flask-mongoengine

I am building python backend for SPA (Angular) using MongoDB.

Here is what I use: `Python 3.4`, `MongoDB 3`, `Flask`, `flask-mongoengine` and `flask-restful`

Now I receive the following JSON from my backend:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "55c737029380f82fbf52eec3"
        },
        "created_at": {
            "$date": 1439129906376
        },
        "desc": "Description.....",
        "title": "This is title"
    },
    etc...
]
```

And **I want to receive something like that**:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "55c737029380f82fbf52eec3",
        "created_at": 1439129906376,
        "desc": "Description.....",
        "title": "This is title"
    },
    etc...
]
```

My code for now:

```
from flask import json
from vinnie import app
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from vinnie.models.movie import Movie

api = Api(app)

class Movies(Resource):
    def get(self):
        movies = json.loads(Movie.objects().all().to_json())
        return movies

api.add_resource(Movies, '/movies')
```

Model:

```
import datetime
from vinnie import db

class Movie(db.Document):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    desc = db.StringField(required=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

What is the best way to format convenient JSON for front-end?

Comment: So Why? Really, these identifiers *"Serve a purpose"* of indentifying an "object type" that your end application *really should* be aware of. There are aways other ways, and the the alternate JSON serializers already available will just do this as the general "stringify" methods on objects will ignore this "type" information on export. The basic here is use the standard JSON libary `puts` or `loads` instead of the BSON variant. But you will be loosing the valid information for doing so.

Comment: In python most objects toString method will return the value of the object property with the $ prefixing it, i.e. for a objectId it will return only the hex string, not an object with the $id property containing a hex string. The simplest way of doing what you want is to iterate the dict detecting the objects and then doing the required operations on them

Comment: @Blakes Seven So, how do I get JSON instead of BSON?

Comment: @Sammaye I already thought about that and tried. But it's really inconvenient to do it manually and I am sure there are better (already implemented) solutions to this problem.

Comment: Have you considered overriding `to_json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confident you want to get rid of all the similar cases, then you can certainly write code that matches that pattern.  For example:

```
info = [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "55c737029380f82fbf52eec3"
        },
        "created_at": {
            "$date": 1439129906376
        },
        "desc": "Description.....",
        "title": "This is title"
    },
    #etc...
]

def fix_array(info):
    ''' Change out dict items in the following case:
           - dict value is another dict
           - the sub-dictionary only has one entry
           - the key in the subdictionary starts with '$'
        In this specific case, one level of indirection
        is removed, and the dict value is replaced with
        the sub-dict value.
    '''
    for item in info:
        for key, value in item.items():
            if not isinstance(value, dict) or len(value) != 1:
                continue
            (subkey, subvalue), = value.items()
            if not subkey.startswith('$'):
                continue
            item[key] = subvalue

fix_array(info)
print(info)
```

This will return this:

```
[{'title': 'This is title', 'created_at': 1439129906376, 'desc': 'Description.....', '_id': '55c737029380f82fbf52eec3'}]
```

Obviously, reformatting that with JSON is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Right now I use your approach, but I found a better approach which I described in my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a neat solution to my problem in `flask-restful` extension which I use.

It provides `fields` module.

> Flask-RESTful provides an easy way to control what data you actually render in your response. With the fields module, you can use whatever objects (ORM models/custom classes/etc.) you want in your resource. fields also lets you format and filter the response so you don’t have to worry about exposing internal data structures.
>
> It’s also very clear when looking at your code what data will be rendered and how it will be formatted.

Example:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, fields, marshal_with

resource_fields = {
    'name': fields.String,
    'address': fields.String,
    'date_updated': fields.DateTime(dt_format='rfc822'),
}

class Todo(Resource):
    @marshal_with(resource_fields, envelope='resource')
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        return db_get_todo()  # Some function that queries the db
```

[Flask-RESTful Output Fields Documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.4/fields.html)